# Entity Framework 6 not inserting Rows in table even though has primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a multi-project solution. In my EF 6 project Gilbane,RREM.Data, I have an EF model which includes a table TransactionLog. Then, I have a project Gilbane.RREM.Logging which includes a function:

```
public static void RecordTransaction(string appId, string transactionId, DateTime time, string sourceInterface,
            string sourceSystem, string tranId, string response, int interfaceId)
        {
            using (RREM_GilbaneEntities entities = new RREM_GilbaneEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    var transactionLog = new TransactionLog
                    {
                        transactionID = transactionId,
                        created = DateTime.Now,
                        sourceInterface = sourceInterface,
                        sourceSystem = sourceSystem,
                        appID = appId,
                        GilbaneTransactionID = tranId,
                        response = response,
                        sourceIP = null,
                        SourceID = interfaceId,
                    };

                    entities.TransactionLogs.Add(transactionLog);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LogError(appId, ex.ToString(), "RecordTransaction", transactionId, "", interfaceId, "CommonLibrary");
                }
            }
```

Finally, I have another assembly which calls the RecordTransaction call. I step through and watch ReordTransaction execute without error. It just doesn't put anything in the TransactionLog table! This is despite it having a declared primary key. Any ideas?

Edit - The EF class library has a model generated from a database:

```
public partial class RREM_GilbaneEntities : DbContext
    {
        public RREM_GilbaneEntities()
            : base("name=RREM_GilbaneEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ErrorLog> ErrorLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TransactionLog> TransactionLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<transactionController> transactionControllers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<TransactionOutgoingQueue> TransactionOutgoingQueues { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<respons> responses { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting a error, it's because EF is storing. Here's my guess. Take a look at your App_data folder, probably there's a file in there, and it is where you can find your records.

How to solve this:

1. be sure that you set the correct connection string.
2. Set the connection string name with the same name of the class that inherit from DbContext class.

Comment: No AppData folder. These are being called either through a WCF web service or a console app, both with the same results. The connection string is set to a big SQL Server database. It was also generated from the model.

Comment: be sure that your configuration file don't have a <entityFramework> section

Comment: on your class that inherit from DbContext, pass the connection string name.

Comment: public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext()
        : base("ConnectionStringName")
    {
    }
}

Comment: Which config file should not have the <entityFramework> section?

Comment: I don't have a context. I am using the one generated my the model. That worked in the past.

Comment: RREM_GilbaneEntities is your context and the name of your connection string. I believe that you don't have a connection string with this name in your .config file. It's my guess. The best way to solve this is put a breakpoint and/or enable intellitrace to debug your app.

Comment: I have a connection string with that name in my config file.